# Conditional formatting of a range based on another range in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I want to have conditional formatting for sheet1 (Columns A-E) in such a way so that cell values which match with the values present in sheet2 (Column A) should be highlighted in red.

I am sharing this [example output sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qo9ks9PLnUBSsVKY4z-Ce3Xe7wuQqpmCxyAjNHH5tDY/edit#gid=1972512087) for your reference.

Please help me out, if it is possible please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule:

```
=countif(indirect("sheet2!A2:A"), A2)
```

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sUQxQ23jyDZ1okfQJ74GNYLEayrQHoEx9WzAkF7M5oM/edit#gid=1972512087).

Answer (score 2):

You can't simply refer to other sheet in Google Sheets conditional formatting, trick is to use `INDIRECT` when referring to other sheets.

Range `A2:I20`

Formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,INDIRECT("Sheet2!$A$12:$A$18"),1,FALSE)>0
```

Or

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A11:a18"),A2)
```

Result:
[image]